# Related rates. surface area from differentiating volume or from the shape directly?

Tags: calculus

**My Query**

In the below answer, it is stated that the SA is $3\left(x\left(t\right)\right)^2$. (volume differentiated).

Why can/should this be used? And why not $6\left(x\left(t\right)\right)^2$ by working out the surface area from the information about side length?

**Original Question**

An ice cube melts at a rate proportional to its surface area. The ice remains cubical while melting.

a) Let the length of one side of the cube at time $t$ equal to $x\left(t\right)$. Write down the volume $V$ of the ice in terms of $x\left(t\right)$.

b) By differentiating your answer to (a) with respect to $t$, show that $\frac{dx}{dt}$ is constant.

**Mark Scheme**

a) $V = \left(x\left(t\right)\right)^3$

b) Use the chain rule to differentiate.

$\frac{dV}{dt}=3\left(x\left(t\right)\right)^2\frac{dx}{dt}$

**Since the surface area $A$ is equal to $3\left(x\left(t\right)\right)^2$** we have

$\frac{dV}{dt}=\frac{dx}{dt}\cdot A$

We are told that the ice melts at a rate proportional to its surface area. So

$\frac{dV}{dt}=kA$.

This means that $\frac{dx}{dt}=k$ which is constant.

Comment: You are correct --- surface area of cube with side length $a$ is $6a^2.$ Book maybe had typo. Doesn't affect main argument about rate.

Answer (score 1):

In general, surface area is **not** the derivative of volume. It happens to be the case for the sphere (well, derivative w.r.t. radius, not time), for instance, but not in general: you have to use a different parameter instead of side length for other shapes.

So yes, for this, you're correct on the surface area; it would be

$$A = 6x^2(t)  $$

However, this typo in the marking scheme is easily remedied, and doesn't really affect the problem, as

$$\frac{dV}{dt} = 3 x^2(t) \frac{dx}{dt} = \frac{A}{2} \frac{dx}{dt} = k A$$

Consequently,

$$\frac{dx}{dt} = \frac k 2$$

giving the constancy in rate we still desire.